# React Carousel - images with different widths display wrong

Tags: css, reactjs, carousel, slideshow, react-hooks

I have an array of URLs that I am passing in as a prop to a slide component. Only one URL is passed at a time using a stateful index. Whenever the right button is clicked, the index is incremented by 1 and vice versa for the left. This is working to display the next URL in the array; however, the images seem to repeat even though I set no-repeat on the background. This is due to the images being different widths and some being smaller than the last. I've tried setting the parent container to a set width so that the slide class is 100% the width of the parent but this doesn't seem to be working for me. Below are the two components that I'm using and the styles file.

```
//Parent carousel component
const HeroImage = ({state}) => {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    var imgUrls = [];

    const goToPrevSlide = () => {
        setIndex(index - 1);
    }
    const goToNextSlide = () => {
        setIndex(index + 1);
    }

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <StyledHeroImage>
                <div className="slider-wrapper">
                        {state.heroImage.map(image => {
                            imgUrls.push(`${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${BACKDROP_SIZE}${image.backdrop_path}`);
                        })}
                        <Slide title={state.heroImage.original_title} text={state.heroImage.overview} image={imgUrls[index]}/>
                </div>

                <LeftArrow goToPrevSlide={goToPrevSlide}/>
                <RightArrow goToNextSlide={goToNextSlide}/>
            </StyledHeroImage>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

//child Slide Component
const Slide = ({image, text, title}) => {
    const styles = {
        background: `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 39%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 41%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%), url(${image})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
    }
    return(
    <div className="slide" style={styles}>
        <div className="heroimage-content">
            <div className="heroimage-text">
                <h1>{title}</h1>
                <p>{text}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>     
    )
}

//Styles file
export const StyledHeroImage = styled.div`
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    .slider-wrapper{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .slide{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .arrow{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: #f9f9f9;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: transform ease-in .1s;
    }

    .nextArrow {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 25px;
        z-index: 999;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .backArrow {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 25px;
        z-index: 999;
        color: #fff;
      }

      .fa-arrow-right:before, .fa-arrow-left:before {
        color: #222
      }
`;
```

Comment: Try adding `object-fit: cover` to the images.

Comment: Unfortunately, that had no effect.